# Is "school" applicable to higher education?

Tags: word-usage

I want to specify in my work calendar that I am away on Mondays because I study at the university on Mondays.
Is it correct to say Monday is a "School day"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "school" can be used to refer to any organization where something is taught. Here is one of the definitions (according to dictionary.com):

> any institution at which instruction is given in a particular discipline.

Another definition from the same source directly answers your question:

> a college or university.

It's more common for people to mean grade school when they mention school, so it makes sense to specify that you mean university. But there's no error in calling a university a school.

Comment: In the UK, *school* is generally understood to mean primary or secondary school. *College* or *university* is normally used for tertiary education. It always trips me up when someone says that they are at school in Stack Overflow. I assume that they are school-kids when, in fact, they are studying for a degree.

Comment: @MickSharpe - This is a UK/US difference.  In the US saying "school" is perfectly idiomatic (while saying "at college" or "at university" would draw strange looks).

Comment: Yes, there is a great divide between the terminology of tertiary education in the US as compared to the UK and vice-versa. Our American friends refer to school or grade school in situations when their British counterparts would say or write college or university. However, the Brits still refer to a "Med School" at university or teaching hospital, likewise a Law School for budding lawyers.  In the US, Law Schools are always postgraduate institutions whereas in the UK they cover both undergraduate and postgraduate studies.

Comment: @HotLicks How would it draw strange looks in the US to say that someone’s *at college*? Because you yourself would instead say *in college*? It seems pretty normal to me.

Comment: @tchrist - "At college" would just cause a raised eyebrow.  "At university", on the other hand, is completely non-idiomatic in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks I cannot imagine "at college" even being noticed at all.

Comment: @tchrist - You've apparently lived in several different countries and you hobnob with folks from all over the world, so I suspect you've become "desensitized" to language that is not idiomatic AmE.  To me a speaker saying "at college" (in some contexts) would strongly suggest a British influence.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think I learned that at college. An American one.

Comment: @Mitch - It depends on the context.  In your sentence "in college" would be slightly more idiomatic.  But saying "In 1997 I was at college" would be completely non-idiomatic.

Comment: @HotLicks OK, sure context is important for these differences (eg in AmE it is definitely 'wrong' to say either 'in hospital' or 'at hospital' which I understand is the proper BrE way). Except I still disagree in fact. That is, 'I was at college then' sounds perfectly fine to my parochial AmE ears.